# Error loading JavaScript with jasmine-maven-plugin within Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, requirejs, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I am somewhat frequently receiving the following error loading javascript internal to our application while running Jasmine tests using the jasmine-maven-plugin. This seems to only happen when run in our CI environment (Jenkins) and does not happen every time the tests are run. I have verified that Jetty is started and listening on the specified port.

Has anyone encountered this before? If so, is there a solution to stabilize the build?

Plugin config:

```
<groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
<artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <debug>true</debug>
    <!-- Instruct plugin on where to find our require.js -->
    <specRunnerTemplate>REQUIRE_JS</specRunnerTemplate>
    <!-- Location of the JS source -->
    <jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/web3/js</jsSrcDir>
    <!-- Location of the Jasmine Specs -->
    <jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript</jsTestSrcDir>
    <preloadSources>
        <source>vendor/require-2.1.9.js</source>
        <source>vendor/jquery-1.4.2.min.js</source>
        <source>utils/jasmine.extensions.js</source>
        <!-- Load the require.js config file. By default, jasmine-maven-plugin looks for require.js if not set by deprecated scriptLoaderPath property. -->
        <source>main.js</source>
    </preloadSources>
    <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jasmine-maven-plugin:1.3.1.3:test (default) @ collaterate-pub ---
2013-12-31 10:52:34.521:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
2013-12-31 10:52:34.557:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:38921
[INFO] Executing Jasmine Specs
Dec 31, 2013 10:52:39 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage loadExternalJavaScriptFile
SEVERE: Error loading JavaScript from [http://localhost:38921/web3/js/vendor/knockout-3.0.0.js].
java.io.IOException: Unable to download JavaScript from 'http://localhost:38921/web3/js/vendor/knockout-3.0.0.js' (status 404).
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1125)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1059)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:266)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:714)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:91)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:664)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:601)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:576)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1005)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:53)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:101)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It works everywhere but in the jenkins machine. I think it is a HtmlUnit bug. I switched to PhantomJS and the problem went away...

Comment: Thanks! I suspect it is also a bug with HtmlUnit. I have upgraded to PhantomJS and have not encountered the issue again.